# Android BroadCastReceiver not working with custom actions

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to implement a simple BroadCastReceiver with a custom action that pops a toast in the `onReceive()` method of the receiver but it is not working for some mysterious reason!!

The main activity only has a button that broadcasts an intent when clicked.
I'm not sure if it is a problem with naming the action.
Any help would be appreciated.

MainActivity :

```
   package com.example.tsupt.bcr;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void broadcastIntent(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.tsupt.bcr.CUSTOM_INTENT");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

The broadcast receiver :

```
public class BR extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"It worked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("It worked");

}}
```

The manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tsupt.bcr">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <receiver android:name="com.example.tsupt.bcr.BR">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.tsupt.bcr.CUSTOM_INTENT">
                    </action>
                </intent-filter>

            </receiver>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The button from the layout file:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="broadcastIntent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, the `<receiver>` element should be a sibling of the `<activity>` element instead of a child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tsupt.bcr">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.tsupt.bcr.BR">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.tsupt.bcr.CUSTOM_INTENT">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, but unfortunately that didn't work as well.

Comment: When running the app I get this in the android monitor:
com.example.tsupt.bcr I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:com.example.tsupt.bcr.CUSTOM_INTENT, mPermissionType:0
Does that mean anything is going wrong?

Comment: Yes it worked.
The problem was with the device I was testing the app on.

Comment: That's surprising, AFAIK the receiver element is ignored if it's nested in an activity element

Answer (score 0):

Actually it worked after all.
The problem seems to be with my huawei honor 5x that I was testing my app on.
There is this battery saving ways huawei phones use and that looks like the source of the problem.

Comment: So you could fix the problem by turning off battery optimization? What Android version were you running back then? I am having a similar problem with a bunch of Huawei phones and we cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: Actually no I couldn't, Huawei does not give you control of all battery optimization features.
I just started using another phone for testing.
I also had many problems with Huawei phones running background services as well, so basically I gave up on using Huawei phones for testing android apps.